# What is the query to achieve this with two sql tables in (my)sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables A, B like this:

```
A.id
A.created
----
B.id
B.data
B.aId
```

I want to select all `B.data` that meet the following criteria:

- `A.created` not null
- `B.aId` = `A.id`

My understanding is that I could solve this by using subqueries, but I suspect it 's a case for a JOIN statement. If so, I 'd really like to see how it 's done :)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select *
from A
join B on A.id = B.aId
where A.created is not null
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from A 
inner join B on A.id = B.aId and A.created is not null
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I selected the first answers since they are the same.